# Calling function with fewer arguments in Typescript

Tags: typescript, function, optional-parameters

I noticed that Typescript doesn't flag the following issue:

```
const fn = (a: string) => {
  return a; // this is inferred as string, not as string | undefined
}

fn(); // "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0" => this is flagged correctly by Typescript
fn2(undefined); // => no Typescript error
```

Anyone can explain why the second call is not flagged as an error ?
How can I make Typescript flag such issue correctly ?

Comment: Do you not have `--strictNullChecks` enabled?  If not then `undefined` and `null` are valid members of every type, and thus this has nothing to do with number of arguments.  It's that `undefined` is a valid `string`.  If you don't like that, then turn on `--strictNullChecks`

Comment: @jcalz You're right, thanks ! That was the cause